# Is my usage of 'had been' correct?

Tags: tenses

I am writing a story in first person singular past tense...Is the following usage of 'had been' in the sentence correct.

> Canab was a massively multiplayer online game designed and developed
>   by Digital Dreams which was started ten years back. It **had been** five
>   years that I was working as a game designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a passive voice but I use it all the time. My editors are fine with it. I use Grammarly and it doesn't like the passive aspect of the words however when I tried to change it to a non-passive the sentences sounded jerky.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hello, Jonnathan. Can you find a reliable reference allowing the coupling of 'It had been five years that' with 'I was working'?

Comment: If I was writing the sentence I would word it this way:

Comment: Canab was a massive multiplayer online game, designed and developed by Digital Dreams, a company started ten years ago. It has been five years since I worked there as a game designer.